# Is irqbalance a bad thing?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, cpu, cpufreq

I am using cpufreq gnome extension and it give's me warning [irqbalance detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjnKd.jpg). Is that something to worry about? And if I somehow stop irqbalance will that affect the processor?

Comment: Posted at same time and probably related as a bug: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093161/strange-process-irqbalance

Comment: https://github.com/konkor/cpufreq/issues/48

Comment: Same question here. It shows up on my system and won't go away.

Answer (score 3):

IRQ stands for Interrupt Request and basically is where the CPU can expect a particular device to interrupt it when a device sends the computer signals about its operation. For example, when a printer has finished printing, it sends an interrupt signal to the computer.

IRQBalance is a Linux daemon that distributes interrupts over among the processors and cores in your computer system. It's mostly used in a server configuration where multiple devices like network cards, hard drives and whatnot will be competing for CPU's attention and it helps distribute hardware interrupts across processors on a multiprocessor system in order to increase performance.

For a workstation or laptop, cpufreq's author recommends uninstalling irqbalance and states his reasons:

1. irqbalance doesn’t support fully all kernel features to an example a turning on/off core threads supported by the extension. If you have installed irqbalance package and turn off some cores you can get freezes or not working devices like wi-fi, bluetooth, video cards, sound cards…
2. irqbalance is not a part of the Linux kernel.
3. It designed for special server configurations with many RAID/HDD/SDD controllers.
4. Only Debian Flowers have the irqbalance installed because Debian is very Server oriented. Red Hat doesn’t have installed irqbalance by default but it doesn’t make Red Hat less server OS.
5. It keeps all Linux core threads working so its not good for power saving, especially for laptops.
6. Any user-space application (like games, compilation…) can not get 100% of CPU resources on any thread because it’s always sharing this resources with IO tasks.

I'll add on top of that two more reasons on when one should not use IRQBalance:

- Manually pinning apps/IRQ’s to specific cores for a very good reason (low latency, realtime requirements, etc.)
- Virtual Guests. It does not really make sense because unless you are pinning the guest to specific CPUs and IRQs and dedicated net/storage hardware, you will likely not see the benefits you would on bare metal.

**TL/DR**: to uninstall it, just `sudo apt-get remove irqbalance` and reboot your machine.

Answer (score 1):

[this FAQ](http://konkor.github.io/cpufreq/faq/) explains what it is. It balances load on the cores, which is good for servers. On desktop that means you cannot get 100 proc on any core because allready used for other processes.